# Lodash overSome only applying first predicate

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to include both "zip" and "country", but somehow only "zip" is included. What am I doing wrong?

```
const arr = ['county', 'zip', 'town'];
const func = filter(overSome(equals('zip'), equals('county')));
const ans = func(arr);
console.log(ans);
// Output: ['zip']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`overSome`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#overSome) takes 1 argument: an *array* of predicates. Currently you are providing multiple arguments. Change that line to:

```js
const func = filter(overSome([equals('zip'), equals('county')]));
```

Only your "zip" matches because that's the one argument lodash was looking for.